# Unable to create Storage Sync Cloud Endpoint

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

When i am trying to create cloud endpoint from terraform script in azure i am getting following error,

> Error: waiting for creation of Storage Sync Cloud Endpoint: (Cloud Endpoint Name “azbackup001zscallerc-file-sync-grp-CE” / Sync Group Name “azbackup001zscallerc-file-sync-grp” / Storage Sync Service Name “azbackup001zscallerc-file-sync” / Resource Group “RG”): Code=“-2134364065” Message=“Unable to read specified storage account. Please check the permissions and try again after some time.”

however when i am creating the same from azure portal i am able to create without any issues. I have checked all my permissions and even from global admin account as well, i am unable to do so. Please assist the possible solution

Please assist on checking permission issue as i can do same thing from az cli as well as powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is even having issues with global admin account,Check When creation of Cloud Endpoint setup permission to that storage sync service that cloud sync is dependent on.

- See [Storage Sync  service  errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/file-sync/file-sync-troubleshoot?tabs=portal1%2Cazure-portal#common-troubleshooting-steps) : **`make sure Azure File Sync has access to the storage account.`**

[image]

```
resource "azurerm_storage_sync" "example" {
  name                = "kaexample-ss"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
}

resource "azurerm_storage_sync_group" "example" {
  name            = "kaexample-ss-group"
  storage_sync_id = azurerm_storage_sync.example.id
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "kaaexample"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share" "example" {
  name                 = "kaexample-share"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  quota                = 50
  acl {
    id = "GhostedRecall"
    access_policy {
      permissions = "r"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_sync_cloud_endpoint" "example" {
  name                  = "example-ss-ce"
  storage_sync_group_id = azurerm_storage_sync_group.example.id
  file_share_name       = azurerm_storage_share.example.name
  storage_account_id    = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
}
```

[image]

Please check this [Az.StorageSync: Cloud endpoint creation access rigths failure issue  · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/9531)